# can't get href from beautifulsoup from 'a class'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the href from this web site,
but I can't find the way to do that, I tried using this:

```
busqueda = requests.get('https://autos.mercadolibre.com.ar/vento/_DisplayType_LF')
auto_cont = BeautifulSoup(busqueda.content)
auto_cont.find_all('a',{'class':'item__info-title'}, href = True)
```

But there is a '< span>' content and I can't overcome that.

Answer (score 1):

`find_all` has been explained. However, your selector is going to produce duplicates as it will pull the same urls from title and price. Instead, I would use a [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) and a different class for parent and add a child `a` tag to get the unique list. I prefer `select` over `find_all`. select applies [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) in order to match on elements. All these `a` tags have an `href` so no need to add a test.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get('https://autos.mercadolibre.com.ar/volkswagen/vento/_DisplayType_LF')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
links = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('.list-view-item-title > a')]
```

**Child combinator:**

> The child combinator (>) is placed between two CSS selectors. It
>   matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are
>   the children of elements matched by the first.

---

Ref:

1. https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html?highlight=select_one#css-selectors

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Beautiful Soup, it is important to understand that the `find_all` method will return a list of tags that match your requirements. Your issue is that you want the `href` attribute of those tags. To do that, you can use the notation `tag['attr']` on each tag. To do that we will iterate through the returned tags.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

busqueda = requests.get('https://autos.mercadolibre.com.ar/vento/_DisplayType_LF')
auto_cont = BeautifulSoup(busqueda.content)
print([tag['href'] for tag in auto_cont.find_all('a',{'class':'item__info-title'}, href = True)])
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```py
>>> import requests
>>> s = requests.Session()
>>> resp = s.get("https://autos.mercadolibre.com.ar/vento/_DisplayType_LF")
>>> from lxml import html
>>> doc = html.fromstring(resp.text)
>>> doc.xpath("//a[@class='item__info-title']")
[<Element a at 0x11c005688>, <Element a at 0x11c0059a8>, <Element a at 0x11c007e58>, <Element a at 0x11c007ea8>, <Element a at 0x11c007ef8>, <Element a at 0x11c007c78>, <Element a at 0x11c007db8>, <Element a at 0x11c007e08>, <Element a at 0x11c007d68>, <Element a at 0x11c007cc8>, <Element a at 0x11c007d18>, <Element a at 0x11c007bd8>, <Element a at 0x11c007c28>, <Element a at 0x11c007228>, <Element a at 0x11c003318>, <Element a at 0x11c003408>, <Element a at 0x11c0034f8>, <Element a at 0x11c003688>, <Element a at 0x11c0035e8>, <Element a at 0x11c003228>, <Element a at 0x11c003598>, <Element a at 0x11c003458>, <Element a at 0x11c003278>, <Element a at 0x11c003548>, <Element a at 0x11c0034a8>, <Element a at 0x11c003368>, <Element a at 0x11c0033b8>, <Element a at 0x11c0032c8>, <Element a at 0x11c0031d8>, <Element a at 0x11c003188>, <Element a at 0x11c003098>, <Element a at 0x11c003138>, <Element a at 0x11c0030e8>, <Element a at 0x11c003048>, <Element a at 0x11c0036d8>, <Element a at 0x11c003728>, <Element a at 0x11c003778>, <Element a at 0x11c0037c8>, <Element a at 0x11c003818>, <Element a at 0x11c003868>, <Element a at 0x11c0038b8>, <Element a at 0x11c003908>, <Element a at 0x11c003958>, <Element a at 0x11c0039a8>, <Element a at 0x11c0039f8>, <Element a at 0x11c003a48>, <Element a at 0x11c003a98>, <Element a at 0x11c003ae8>, <Element a at 0x11c003b38>, <Element a at 0x11c003b88>, <Element a at 0x11c003bd8>, <Element a at 0x11c003c28>, <Element a at 0x11c003c78>, <Element a at 0x11c003cc8>, <Element a at 0x11c003d18>, <Element a at 0x11c003d68>, <Element a at 0x11c003db8>, <Element a at 0x11c003e08>, <Element a at 0x11c003e58>, <Element a at 0x11c003ea8>, <Element a at 0x11c003ef8>, <Element a at 0x11c003f48>, <Element a at 0x11c003f98>, <Element a at 0x11c006048>, <Element a at 0x11c006098>, <Element a at 0x11c0060e8>, <Element a at 0x11c006138>, <Element a at 0x11c006188>, <Element a at 0x11c0061d8>, <Element a at 0x11c006228>, <Element a at 0x11c006278>, <Element a at 0x11c0062c8>, <Element a at 0x11c006318>, <Element a at 0x11c006368>, <Element a at 0x11c0063b8>, <Element a at 0x11c006408>, <Element a at 0x11c006458>, <Element a at 0x11c0064a8>, <Element a at 0x11c0064f8>, <Element a at 0x11c006548>, <Element a at 0x11c006598>, <Element a at 0x11c0065e8>, <Element a at 0x11c006638>, <Element a at 0x11c006688>, <Element a at 0x11c0066d8>, <Element a at 0x11c006728>, <Element a at 0x11c006778>, <Element a at 0x11c0067c8>, <Element a at 0x11c006818>, <Element a at 0x11c006868>, <Element a at 0x11c0068b8>, <Element a at 0x11c006908>, <Element a at 0x11c006958>, <Element a at 0x11c0069a8>, <Element a at 0x11c0069f8>, <Element a at 0x11c006a48>, <Element a at 0x11c006a98>, <Element a at 0x11c006ae8>, <Element a at 0x11c006b38>, <Element a at 0x11c006b88>]
>>> doc.xpath("//a[@class='item__info-title']/@href")
['https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-793135798-volkswagen-vento-20t-sportline-2007-4p-dh-aa-san-blas-auto-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-793135798-volkswagen-vento-20t-sportline-2007-4p-dh-aa-san-blas-auto-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-788603493-volkswagen-vento-25-advance-plus-manual-2015-rpm-moviles-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-788603493-volkswagen-vento-25-advance-plus-manual-2015-rpm-moviles-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-774423219-vento-comfortline-0km-2019-volkswagen-linea-nueva-vw-2018-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-774423219-vento-comfortline-0km-2019-volkswagen-linea-nueva-vw-2018-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-795714156-volksvagen-vento-advance-plus-25-anticipo-290000-y-ctas-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-795714156-volksvagen-vento-advance-plus-25-anticipo-290000-y-ctas-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-792330462-volkswagen-vento-25-luxury-wood-tiptronic-2009-imolaautos--_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-792330462-volkswagen-vento-25-luxury-wood-tiptronic-2009-imolaautos--_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-763941297-vento-highline-0km-automatico-auto-nuevos-volkswagen-vw-2019-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-763941297-vento-highline-0km-automatico-auto-nuevos-volkswagen-vw-2019-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-791000164-volkswagen-vento-20-advance-115cv-2015-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-791000164-volkswagen-vento-20-advance-115cv-2015-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-788125558-volkswagen-vento-14-tsi-highline-150cv-at-2017-rpm-moviles-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-788125558-volkswagen-vento-14-tsi-highline-150cv-at-2017-rpm-moviles-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-777140113-volkswagen-vento-gli-dsg-nav-my-18-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-777140113-volkswagen-vento-gli-dsg-nav-my-18-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-795016462-volkswagen-vento-25-luxury-tiptronic-2011-imolaautos--_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-795016462-volkswagen-vento-25-luxury-tiptronic-2011-imolaautos--_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-792487602-volkswagen-25-luxury-170cv-tiptronic-2015-rpm-moviles-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-792487602-volkswagen-25-luxury-170cv-tiptronic-2015-rpm-moviles-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-789645020-volkswagen-vento-20-advance-115cv-summer-package-371-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-789645020-volkswagen-vento-20-advance-115cv-summer-package-371-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-775185003-vw-0km-volkswagen-vento-14-comfortline-highline-financiado-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-775185003-vw-0km-volkswagen-vento-14-comfortline-highline-financiado-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-774502893-volkswagen-vento-14-comfortline-150cv-at-dsg-0km-2019-vw-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-774502893-volkswagen-vento-14-comfortline-150cv-at-dsg-0km-2019-vw-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-795734858-volkswagen-vento-25-luxury-tiptronic-2009-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-795734858-volkswagen-vento-25-luxury-tiptronic-2009-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-795501655-volkswagen-vento-25-luxury-170cv-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-795501655-volkswagen-vento-25-luxury-170cv-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-792476554-volkswagen-vento-14-comfortline-150cv-at-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-792476554-volkswagen-vento-14-comfortline-150cv-at-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-790622152-volkswagen-vento-14-tsi-comfortline-dsg-como-nuevo-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-790622152-volkswagen-vento-14-tsi-comfortline-dsg-como-nuevo-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-741867064-volkswagen-vento-14-comfortline-150cv-at-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-741867064-volkswagen-vento-14-comfortline-150cv-at-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-770677950-volkswagen-vento-20-sportline-tsi-200cv-dgs-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-770677950-volkswagen-vento-20-sportline-tsi-200cv-dgs-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-756888148-volkswagen-vento-14-highline-150cv-at-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-756888148-volkswagen-vento-14-highline-150cv-at-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-792470321-volkswagen-vento-highline-14-at-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-792470321-volkswagen-vento-highline-14-at-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-780443475-volkswagen-vento-20-sportline-tsi-200cv-bi-xenon-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-780443475-volkswagen-vento-20-sportline-tsi-200cv-bi-xenon-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-775185107-vw-0km-volkswagen-vento-14-comfortline-highline-financio-ya-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-775185107-vw-0km-volkswagen-vento-14-comfortline-highline-financio-ya-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-763006237-volkswagen-nuevo-vento-comfortline-14-tsi-150cv-autotag-a7-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-763006237-volkswagen-nuevo-vento-comfortline-14-tsi-150cv-autotag-a7-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-792344363-volkswagen-vento-14-comfortline-150cv-at-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-792344363-volkswagen-vento-14-comfortline-150cv-at-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-789195021-volkswagen-vento-comfortline-motor-14-at-tiptronic-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-789195021-volkswagen-vento-comfortline-motor-14-at-tiptronic-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-787103884-volkswagen-vento-comfortline-14-150-cv-dsg-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-787103884-volkswagen-vento-comfortline-14-150-cv-dsg-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-795438039-volkswagen-vento-14-highline-150cv-at-financio-leasing-0km-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-795438039-volkswagen-vento-14-highline-150cv-at-financio-leasing-0km-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-785080712-vento-25-advance-manual-permutofinancio-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-785080712-vento-25-advance-manual-permutofinancio-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-739533930-volkswagen-vento-20-tsi-i-2017-i-permuto-i-financio-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-739533930-volkswagen-vento-20-tsi-i-2017-i-permuto-i-financio-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-787212749-volkswagen-vento-14-comfortline-150cv-at-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-787212749-volkswagen-vento-14-comfortline-150cv-at-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-785738851-volkswagen-vento-advance-summer-package-20-unico-dueno--_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-785738851-volkswagen-vento-advance-summer-package-20-unico-dueno--_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-788508924-volkswagen-vento-25-advance-tiptronic-2007-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-788508924-volkswagen-vento-25-advance-tiptronic-2007-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-790696083-volkswagen-vento-14-highline-150cv-at-0km-tiptronic-nuevo-1-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-790696083-volkswagen-vento-14-highline-150cv-at-0km-tiptronic-nuevo-1-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-788446116-volkswagen-vento-20-sportline-tsi-200-2013-luxury-tdi-bora-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-788446116-volkswagen-vento-20-sportline-tsi-200-2013-luxury-tdi-bora-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-752087027-volkswagen-nuevo-vento-14-highline-0-km-2019-autotag-cb-a7-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-752087027-volkswagen-nuevo-vento-14-highline-0-km-2019-autotag-cb-a7-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-781505508-nuevo-vento-entrega-inmediata-tomo-usado-moto-auto-18-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-781505508-nuevo-vento-entrega-inmediata-tomo-usado-moto-auto-18-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-742485511-volkswagen-vento-14-highline-150cv-0km-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-742485511-volkswagen-vento-14-highline-150cv-0km-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-769182377-vw-volkswagen-vento-gli-230-cv-preventa-2019-0-km-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-769182377-vw-volkswagen-vento-gli-230-cv-preventa-2019-0-km-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-790609996-volkswagen-vento-20-luxury-i-140cv-dsg-automatico-diesel-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-790609996-volkswagen-vento-20-luxury-i-140cv-dsg-automatico-diesel-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-790664862-volkswagen-vento-25-luxury-170cv-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-790664862-volkswagen-vento-25-luxury-170cv-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-784454164-volkswagen-vento-25-luxury-170cv-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-784454164-volkswagen-vento-25-luxury-170cv-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-769868579-0km-volkswagen-vento-14-highline-150cv-at-2019-tasa-159-d-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-769868579-0km-volkswagen-vento-14-highline-150cv-at-2019-tasa-159-d-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-787564006-volkswagen-vento-20t-sportline-automatico-dsg-2013-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-787564006-volkswagen-vento-20t-sportline-automatico-dsg-2013-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-788080154-volkswagen-vento-20-sportline-tsi-200cv-dgs-2013-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-788080154-volkswagen-vento-20-sportline-tsi-200cv-dgs-2013-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-771885864-volkswagen-vento-14-comfortline-150cv-aut-sf-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-771885864-volkswagen-vento-14-comfortline-150cv-aut-sf-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-795273990-vento-25-manual-unico-dueno-80000-km-motor-cadenero-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-795273990-vento-25-manual-unico-dueno-80000-km-motor-cadenero-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-769870550-0km-volkswagen-vento-14-highline-150cv-at-2019-tasa-159-f-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-769870550-0km-volkswagen-vento-14-highline-150cv-at-2019-tasa-159-f-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-790653682-volkswagen-vento-25-triptronic-170-cv-cuero-carhaus-_JM', 'https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-790653682-volkswagen-vento-25-triptronic-170-cv-cuero-carhaus-_JM']
```